# How to import a large CSV file whose size is about 300GB?

Tags: csv, dolphindb

I have a large CSV file whose size is about 300GB. I want to know how to import it into DolphinDB.

```py
n=10000000 
dataFilePath="/home/jwu/data/dhbt.csv" 
table(10000:0,`id`time`v`q,[SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE,DOUBLE]) 
//Create table structure 
login(` admin,`123456) 
dbPath1="dfs://dzDatabase" 
db1=database(dbPath1,VALUE,`IBM`MSFT`GM`C`FB`GOOG`V`F`XOM`AMZN`TSLA`PG`S) 
tb1 =db1.createPartitionedTable(trades,`dz,`id) 
//mr required function 
def divideImport(tb, mutable dz) 
{ 
tdata1=select * from tb  
append!(dz, tdata1) 
} 
//divide the data source into 100M 
schema=table(`id`time`v`q as name,`SYMBOL`TIMESTAMP`DOUBLE`DOUBLE as type) 
ds=textChunkDS(dataFilePath,100,,schema) 
mr(ds=ds, mapFunc=divideImport{,tb1} , parallel=false); 
select count(*) from loadTable("dfs://dzDatabase", "dz")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the large CSV file into multiple small files, then use the [mr](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/m/mr.html) to implement distributed computing. The following scripts illustrate how to implement it:

```py
n=10000000
dataFilePath="/home/jwu/data/dhbt.csv"
table(10000:0,`id`time`v`q,[SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE,DOUBLE])
//Create table structure 
login(`admin,`123456)
dbPath1="dfs://dzDatabase"
db1=database(dbPath1,VALUE,`IBM`MSFT`GM`C`FB`GOOG`V`F`XOM`AMZN`TSLA`PG`S)
tb1=db1.createPartitionedTable(trades,`dz,`id)
//function used in mr
def divideImport(tb, mutable dz)
{
tdata1=select * from tb 
append!(dz, tdata1)
}
//divide the data source
schema=table(`id`time`v`q as name,`SYMBOL`TIMESTAMP`DOUBLE`DOUBLE as type)
ds=textChunkDS(dataFilePath,100,,schema)
mr(ds=ds, mapFunc=divideImport{,tb1}, parallel=false);
select count(*) from loadTable("dfs://dzDatabase", "dz")
```